# ExtJs 5 Ajax Request with ASP .NET

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure, extjs

**Despite** my best efforts I am not able to send an Ajax request with Json data to a remote web server.  I do not know what other places I can put enable CORS and am running out of ideas.

**Azure Website App Settings:**

```
 cors:allowOrigins: *
```

**MVC Controller:** I had installed the NuGet Cors package

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

**Web.config:**

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**ExtJs Ajax Request:**

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: app.utilities.url,
            defaultHeaders: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization,Content-Length, X-Requested-With'
            },
            cors: true,
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            params: {
                jsonData: Ext.util.JSON.encode(formData)
            }
```

**Yet I still get:**
     Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at {my url} This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you consider JsonP (JSON with Padding)?

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP

Comment: This probably works, haha. I'm going through and deleting work accounts since today is my last day.  Thanks for answering my question albeit a few years late! Pretty cool to see how much better I am at programming since this question was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Only for the **development** purpose you can set below parameter in your browser.It works for me.

**--disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access**

Comment: That's good to know, but I am currently developing with the application and web API on the same server. Although, I would like to move the application in the future.